# Why does the length of calendar not equal 12

Tags: python

I'm new to python and was trying to create a list of month names. I noticed something odd:

```
len(calendar.month_name) == 12

False
```

Can anyone explain to me why the length of month names is not 12?

Thanky you for any advice!

Comment: have you tried `print(len(calendar.month_name))` and see what it outputs?

Comment: That would only confirm that `len(calendar.month_name)` is some value that isn't 12; it wouldn't explain why it is whatever it is.

Comment: @ElyFialkoff the output of print(len(calendar.month_name)) is 13

Comment: Look below at my answer and the answer posted by @jwodder, which is basically the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Quoting the documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name)

> This follows normal convention of January being month number 1, so it has a length of 13 and `month_name[0]` is the empty string.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help, that makes sense... but I though everything in python started with 0, guess i was wrong :)

Comment: All sequences *do* start with 0, which is why a dummy name is stored as element zero so that the "regular" month numbers line up with the list indices.

Comment: `month[0]` is empty `''`, `month[1]` is `"January"`, `month[2]` is `"February"` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because `calendar.month_name[0] = ''` this is probably to keep things simple for the rest of the months. So January is the first month or month number 1 and is also therefore `calendar.month_name[1]` and so on. This is probably just meant for simplicity. Since index 0 is empty and index 12 is December there are "13" months.